# How to fix "invalid command name" error with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

solved:
as @furas said, I was trying to access email_text after I had already destroyed the window, so email_text no longer existed.

I'm trying to automate a login to a website by grabbing the email and password from an entry using tkinter. The code grabs the email and password and enters it in the site, and succesfully logs in. But I get an error about the email_text.get() line.

Originally I had a prepare() and error() function, so if the login was insuccesful, it would call error() and prompt them to log in again. I had the same error then and wondered if it was an issue with some conflict between widgets in the functions? So I just tried to simplify it into one, but I am still getting the same error. I have 3 different versions of this code and I have been moving bits around, so it's possible that I didnt move something from the other 2 versions that was needed, but I cant figure out which part I could be missing.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import time
from datetime import tzinfo
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

chromedriver = "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://www.soundclick.com/community/SC4/login.cfm")

def get_email_pass():
    while True:
        email = email_text.get()
        password = pass_text.get()
        my_window.destroy()
        xpathEmail = '//*[@id="email"]'
        loginEmail = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathEmail)
        loginEmail.send_keys(email)
        xpathPass = '//*[@id="password"]'
        loginPass = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathPass)
        loginPass.send_keys(password)
        xpathLogin = '//*[@id="loginform"]/div[3]/div[2]/input'
        login = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathLogin)
        login.click()
        time.sleep(5)

        if driver.current_url == "https://www.soundclick.com/bandAdmin2/default.cfm?ipv=0":
                exit


#open tkinter window
my_window=Tk()
#Title
my_window.title('SoundClick Login')
#Color
my_window.configure(background="deep sky blue")
#Instr 
email_label=Label(my_window, text="Please Enter The Email Used To Sign Into SoundClick")
email_label.config(background="deep sky blue", foreground="white")
#Create Entry
email_text = Entry(my_window)
email_text.pack()
pass_label=Label(my_window, text="Please Enter The Password Used To Sign Into SoundClick")
pass_label.config(background="deep sky blue", foreground="white")
pass_text=Entry(my_window)
pass_text.pack()


#Censor Password
pass_text.config(show="*")
song_text = Entry(my_window)
song_label=Label(my_window, text="Please Enter The Name Of The Song You Want To Promote. Warning:cAsE SensItIvE")
song_label.config(background="deep sky blue", foreground="white")
#When Done button is pressed, run cmd done_button
finish_button = Button(my_window, text="Done",command=get_email_pass)
finish_button.config(background="white")
note_label=Label(my_window, text="This information will not be stored anywhere")
note_label.config(background="deep sky blue", foreground="white")

#Positioning
email_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
email_text.grid(row=0, column=1)
pass_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
pass_text.grid(row=1, column=1)
finish_button.grid(row=3, column=0)

my_window.mainloop()
```

The webpage should close if the login is succesful, but instead it stays open and I get this error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1547, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Jon.py", line 14, in get_email_pass
    email = email_text.get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2518, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
TclError: invalid command name ".66283784L"```
````

Comment: your problem can be `while True` inside `get_email_pass()` which runs many times `email_text.get()` - but after running `email_text.get()` first time you run `my_window.destroy()` so `email_text` doesn't exists when `while` runs `email_text.get()` second time. And this can gives error "invalid command name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@furas is right. you are trying to access the contents of the `email` entry. but on the first iteration, after you are closing the window, you are trying to access it again, but it has closed already!

to fix this you can move the `my_window.destroy()` from the `while True` loop to the if statement at the end of the function, so the window will only close after you have connected.